# Replace nested functions

Tags: c, c99, nested-function

I created a c program which uses nested functions from the gnu extension a lot and now I want to make them standard conform with ansi c.

What's the best way to transform nested functions, which access some outer vars to something different.

```
#define lambda(return_type, function_body) \
({ \
    return_type __fn__ function_body \
    __fn__; \
})
```

example usage

```
size_t var1;
size_t var2;
lambda(void, (...) {
    // some code
    lambda(void, (...) {
        // ...
        // do something with var1/var2
        // ..
    }

    // ...
    // do something with var1/var2
}
```

I thought about moving the vars to global scope, so they are known from each "lambda" which would maybe the easiest solution, but I dont want to polute the global scope and I'm not sure, if this is the cleanest way.

---

As asked by some commenters - here's a concrete example

```
/* fill itt*/
int n_method = 0;
void *add_method = lambda(void, (ir_entity *method) {
    int itable_offset = n_method++;
    const char *method_name = get_entity_name(method);

    ir_entity *implementation = get_method_entity(klass, method_name);
    if (implementation == NULL) {
        walk_up_callback(klass, lambda(bool, (ir_type *st) {
            implementation = get_method_entity(st, method_name);
            if (implementation != NULL) {
                insert_itable_method(implementation, itable_offset, interface, init);
            }
            return implementation == NULL;
        }), NULL);
    } else {
        insert_itable_method(implementation, itable_offset, interface, init);
    }
});

walk_up_callback(interface, NULL, lambda(void, (ir_type *klass) {
    if (oo_get_class_is_interface(klass)) {
        walk_table_methods_callback(add_method, klass);
    }
}));
walk_table_methods_callback(add_method, interface);
```

It's a part of a compiler which creates some itables for efficient interface lookups

Comment: Make your functions accept arguments and then pass `var1` and `var2`, or a pointer to them.

Comment: One clean option is to make normal functions that take pointers to those variables, and then dereference to read/write to it.

Comment: Insted of globalize all variable, you could develope an astraction layer that gives you access to variables you need. In this case variable will be private to the AL.

Comment: `static` "global" variables only pollute the current file.

Comment: For those wondering : `__fn__`, despite looking like an implementation detail, is not. It would be a good idea to rename it.

Comment: It would be good to see an actual use of your lambda functions. In the example above, you just create expressions without using them. I assume that you use the lambdas as callback to other functions, no?

Comment: @MOehm I added an example

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks. That code looks a bit like Javascript with its combos of round and curly brackets. Do you have control over the `walk_something` functions? In your example, the callbacks act more or less as loop bodies. Could you redesign the containers to use iterators instead of callbacks?

Comment: Loops would be great, but the walk_* functions are recursive and walk over an tree(class inheritance hierarchy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the callbacks for iteration through containers. If your data structure allows it, you could try to write traversal code by means of iterators, which will allow you to write what now is a separate callback as loop body.

For example, if you have a binary tree, recursive traversal with a callback looks more or less like this:

```
typedef struct node_t node_t;

struct node_t {
    const char *id;
    node_t *left, *right;
};

void traverse(const node_t *node, void (*func)(const node_t *n))
{
    if (node) {
        traverse(node->left, func);
        func(node);
        traverse(node->right, func);
    }
}
```

And it is used like so:

```
traverse(head, lambda(void, (const node_t *n){ puts(n->id); }));
```

As you have noted, in Standard C, the function must be a global function with the restriction that you can't easily and type-safely access data that is not stored in the node itself.

For a standard-compliant and more intuitive way to traverse the tree, you can rewrite the traversal as iterative code and store the state in an iterator:

```
typedef struct node_iter_t node_iter_t;

struct node_iter_t {
    node_t *next;
    node_t *node;
    node_t *stack[32];
    int nstack;
};

int next_node(node_iter_t *it)
{
    it->node = it->next;

    while (it->nstack || it->node) {
        while (it->node) {
            it->stack[it->nstack++] = it->node;
            it->node = it->node->left;
        }

        it->node = it->stack[--it->nstack];
        it->next = it->node->right;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The iterator code is more verbose than the recursive traversal, but the client code is a simple loop, which can access other local variables in the function:

```
node_iter_t it = {head};
int i = 0;

while (next_node(&it)) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", i++, it.node->id);
}
```

Of course, your container might not be suited for such a rewrite.

Comment: I don't exactly used your code, but the idea behind. I replaced my recursive walkers with an iterateable list creation method, which leaves many parts of my code "as is". Sadly, the code needs now more memory and may be slower. I dont made any benchmarks, but the new memory managment wasn't neccessary for the recursive approach

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Yeah, simplicity in the client code comes at the cost of more complex iteration code, data overhead and maybe even data restrictions.

Comment: Side note: The D Programming Language allows objects to be iterated in a `foreach` loop if they provide an `opApply` method. The loop body is passed to that method as a delegate, i.e. a function that captures the environment. This gives you easy iteration and intuitive loop syntax. The requirement for such constructs is clearly there.

Answer (score 2):

**The cleanest, most idiomatic way in my opinion would be to make simple non nested functions which take all of the variables they need as arguments, either by value if they are inputs or via a pointer if outputs.**

If this becomes difficult due to number of variables this is probably a sign of a larger issue in the code and it likely needs more substantial refactoring.

Consider putting groups of closely related variables into structs if you want to lower the number of random loose variables around in the code, this is likely also more expressive. Using inline functions is generally a very untidy method of coding as it promotes large, unclear scopes.

However macros would likely be an even worse solution as they will prevent any chance the compiler has to avoid repeating the code of the nested functions and will pollute the outer scope even more with any variables defined in the nested function.

Globals are possibly the worst solution of all as they expand the scopes to the entire program and in addition are substantially slower to access and will slow down your code enormously. They will also make a variable name collision almost inevitable in a larger program.